# Why is the text editor unable to read characters like " ẻ "?

Tags: 14.04, unicode

It says that the file is corrupted and unable to read such characters in its text editor and marks them whereas Windows just displays them perfectly in its notepad.

[image: The below link to the image attached shows the error]

Comment: More details, please.

Comment: I'm assuming the "ubuntu text editor" is gedit. Have you tried mousepad or leafpad or geany?

Comment: Please add the output of `file /path/to/file`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as the default character encoding, Windows seems to use some other encoding.

You either need to tell GEdit what character encoding to use for that file or to convert the file to UTF-8 (as far as I know Notepad allows you to save a file using UTF-8 encoding)